# How to show a continuous function on $[0,1]$ interval is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Trying out some problems and the title says it all,

> Show that a set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ interval belongs to a vector space

We were told that since the vector addition and multiplication is defined to be continuous in calculus it does not need to be defined, but stuck. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean "Show that a set of continuos functions on [0,1] interval **is** a vector space", not ""**belongs to** a vector space"

Comment: What you have to prove is $\alpha  f$ is still in the space and $f+g$ is still in the space (which are consequence of the continuity)

Comment: Every set belongs to a vector space, the free vector space generated by the set.  This is not so interesting.  The usual notion of sum of functions, and multiplying function by numbers turns this set into a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $V$ with addition and scalar multiplication defined is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ if:

1. $(V, +)$ is a commutative group
2. For all $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb R$ and all $v\in V$, $$\alpha(\beta v) = (\alpha\beta)v$$
3. For all $v\in V$, $1v = v$
4. For all $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb R$ and all $v\in V$, $$(\alpha + \beta)v = \alpha v+\beta v$$
5. For all $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ and all $v,w\in V$, $$\alpha(v+w)=\alpha v + \alpha w.$$

Go step by step. Prove each point individually, none of them is particularly hard.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confused.  What set?  What vector space?  The set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is a vector space: just verify the properties
in the definition of vector space.  For some subset $S$ of these to form a 
vector space, you just have to verify that for any $f$ and $g$ in $S$ and any
real number $c$, $f+g$ and $cf$ are in $S$.